# Azure DevOps: Merging two projects together

Tags: azure-devops, azure-marketplace

A few years ago, our team made the full transition to Azure DevOps.  Before that, we had a mixture of on-prem TFS and Subversion but went to the Azure DevOps as it was easier to maintain project status between our developer and BA teams.  At that time, for each project the team was working on, we just created a new "project" in Azure DevOps, but over the course of the past few years, we have found that using that method doesn't lend itself to helping us track metrics across all of those projects.  We also see that maintaining multiple, separate backlogs is not ideal as we have developers spread across multiple sprints at the same time in different projects without a single place for the team leads or scrum master to fully know what their team members are working on in a single day.

Now, we've made use of queries, but those only go so far, so we've made the decision to merge our projects into a single "project".  My scrum master and I have been looking at Naked Agility's merge tool, as outlined in this link:  https://blog.devopsabcs.com/index.php/2019/06/12/one-project-to-rule-them-all/.

Has anyone used this tool and how well did it work for you?  Also, are there any other options for merging projects together as this tool seems really complex (which the developer states is the case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Azure DevOps: Merging two projects together

Sorry for any inconvenience.

I am afraid merging projects into a project is currently not supported in azure devops.

There is a **Under Review** user voice about [make it possible to move a Team Project between Team Project Collections](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/365365/make-it-possible-to-move-a-team-project-between-te-1.html).

Merging two projects is not a simple task, it contains not only source code, build/release history, workitems and other watch outs were mainly around access and security:

- External API integrations such as Web Apps, Function Apps, JIRA, Service Now
- External inbound app authorisations
- External outbound app authorisations such as Azure Service Principals
- Variable Group authorisations to YAML Build Pipelines
- Library reference updates including KeyVault
- etc

This refactoring ended up being much more work than the code merge itself.

Besides, there is a Azure devops extension [Migration Tools for Azure DevOps](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration), which allow you to migrate Teams, Work Items, and Plans & Suits from one Project to another in Azure DevOps/TFS both within the same Organisation, and between Organisations. Watch the [Video Overview](https://youtu.be/RCJsST0xBCE) to get you started in 30 minutes. This tool is complicated and its not always easy to discover what you need to do.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Leo-Lui-MSFT, thanks for the follow-up.  Yes, I've gone through the video, and even after that it is still pretty complicated, but right now it looks like it is the only road we have to go down at this time.  I will say though that the projects that we are migrating into our current "master" project are all very simple, as they only contain backlogs, repos, wikis, and pipelines.